# forward declaration of viewController class receiving illegal interface qualifier error

Tags: objective-c

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@class ViewController;

@property (strong,nonatomic) ViewController *viewController; 

@end
```

on the line of @class ViewController it says there is an illegal interface qualifier error. What does it mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 14):

just one to add for others, that I got also "illegal interface qualifier error"
and I was 99% sure it's something with forward declaration..but then..on every time I change and try to fix this,xcode gave very strange errors that was not logical.

finally the problem was :
missing @end on other header file..

unlucky...

Comment: I had the same problem.  The header file that was missing the end was not called or even remotely related to the classes that were giving me illegal interface qualifier errors.

Answer (score 10):

Declare

```
@class ViewController;
```

prior to

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the @class ViewController outside of your @interface, like so:

```
@class ViewController;
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;



@property (strong,nonatomic) ViewController *viewController; 

@end
```